# Probability of an event (two random variables are independent)

Tags: probability, independence, rademacher-distribution

Let $n\ge 1$ and $X_1, ...,X_n$ be i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables.

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Let $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1, ..., \varepsilon_n)$, where all $\varepsilon_i$ are i.i.d and $\varepsilon_1=+1$ or $-1$ with equal probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Define $S_{n,\epsilon}=\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i X_i$.

**My question** is how do we calculate $P[S_n \mbox{ and } S_{n,\varepsilon} \mbox{ are independent}]$ with respect to the distribution of $\varepsilon$? i.e. What is $\frac{\text{the numbers of $\varepsilon$ making $S_n$ and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ independent}}{\text{the numbers of all possible $\varepsilon$}}?$ Thanks.

---

I can imagine in some situations $S_n$ and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ are dependent (cf. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430551/why-arent-all-normal-and-rademacher-variables-independent)), but I cannot even think of a concrete situation where $S_n$ and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ are independent. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}(S_n \textit{ and } S_{n, \varepsilon})$? This is not event. Both $S_n$ and $S_{n, \varepsilon}$ are r.v.

Comment: @openspace Sorry for the ambiguity. I just edited the post. We have many choices of $\varepsilon$, some of which make $S_n$ and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ independent and some of which not. $\mathbb{P}(S_n \textit{ and } S_{n, \varepsilon}\mbox{ independent})$ is equivalent to {the numbers of $\varepsilon$ making $S_n$ and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ independent} over {the numbers of all possible $\varepsilon$}.

Comment: There is no event like $X$ and $Y$ are independent. R.v. are independent iff $\mathbb{P}(\{X \in A, Y\in B\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{X \in A\}) \mathbb{P}(\{Y \in B\})$ for all $A, B$ from corresponding sigma-algebras. Just check definition.

Comment: @openspace Let me put in this way. $\varepsilon$ consists of $n$ R.V.s, and $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ depends on these $\varepsilon_n$. For some $\varepsilon_n$, the $S_{n,\varepsilon}$ induced by them are independent of $S_n$, but some are not. Note that our measure space is $(0,1)$, for any measurable subset $E\subseteq (0,1)$ with $P(E)=1/2$, we may define $\varepsilon_1=1$ on $E$ and $-1$ on $(0,1)\setminus E$. There are infinitely many such $E$ and so there are infinitely many choices of $\varepsilon_n$.

Comment: @openspace Hence we can talk about the ratio I wrote in the question, which is what we mean by $P[S_n \mbox{ and } S_{n,\varepsilon} \mbox{ are independent}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon\in\{\pm 1\}^n$.

Let $A=\{i:\varepsilon_i=1\}$, and let $B=\{i:\varepsilon_i=-1\}$.

If $B={\large{\varnothing}}$ then $S_{n,\varepsilon}=S_n$, and if $A={\large{\varnothing}}$ then $S_{n,\varepsilon}=-S_n$, so in both of those cases, the random variables $S_{n,\varepsilon},S_n$ are dependent.

Next assume $A,B$ are both nonempty.

Let random variables $Y,Z$ be given by
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
Y&=\sum_{i\in A}\varepsilon_iX_i\\[4pt]
Z&=\sum_{i\in B}\varepsilon_iX_i\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Since $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables, we get that

- $Y,Z$ are independent.$\\[4pt]$

  $(Y,Z)$ are jointly normal.$\\[4pt]$

  $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,|A|)$ and $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,|B|)$.

It follows that $(Y+Z,Y-Z)$ are also jointly normal.

Noting that $S_{n,\varepsilon}=Y+Z$ and $S_n=Y-Z$, we get that 
\begin{align*}
&
S_{n,\varepsilon},S_n\;\,\text{are independent}
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
Y+Z,Y-Z\;\,\text{are independent}
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
\text{Cov}(Y+Z,Y-Z)=0
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
E\Bigl((Y+Z)(Y-Z)\Bigr)
=
E(Y+Z)E(Y-Z)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
E\Bigl((Y+Z)(Y-Z)\Bigr)
=
0
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
E(Y^2-Z^2)
=
0
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
E(Y^2)=E(Z^2)
\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
|A|=|B|
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Note that $|A|+|B|=n$, hence $|A|=|B|$ implies $n$ is even and
$|A|=|B|={\large{\frac{n}{2}}}$.

Hence for a random choice of $\varepsilon$ from $\{\pm 1\}^n$, the probability that $S_{n,\varepsilon},S_n$
are independent is equal to zero if $n$ is odd, and is equal to
$$
\frac
{
\large{
n\choose{m}
}
}
{2^n}
$$
if $n$ is even, where $m={\large{\frac{n}{2}}}$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Can I ask two canonical questions? How do we derive that $(Y,Z)$ are jointly normal? Also, how to see $(Y+Z,Y-Z)$ are jointly normal? Thanks for help.

Comment: @maths learner: Any nontrivial linear combination $W$ (i.e., not all coefficients equal to zero) of $Y,Z$ is also a nontrivial linear combination of the independent normal random variables $X_1,...,X_n$, hence $W$ is normal, so by definition, $(Y,Z)$ are jointly normal. Similarly, any nontrivial linear combination $V$ of $Y+Z,Y-Z$ is also a nontrivial linear combination of the independent normal random variables $Y,Z$, hence $V$ is normal, so $(Y+Z,Y-Z)$ are jointly normal.